# JQuery Selectors - How can I copy to clipboard with different ids

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
            <h3>Something here</h3>
            <p id="copythis">Copy this code</p>

            <h3>Something here</h3>
            <p id="copythisone">Copy this other text</p>

            <h3>Something here</h3>
            <p id="copythisone">Copy this other text</p>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#copythis').click(function(){

                var text = $("#copythis").get(0)
                var selection = window.getSelection();
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(text);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
                document.execCommand('copy');
            })
        });
    </script>
```

I have different texts to copy (not all at once).

this code works for one text only. How do I work for more than one?

I just changed this part and it worked:

````
```var text = $(this).get(0)```
````

Thaks to @wahwahwah

Comment: Change the ID selector? (If you copy-paste code from the internet, please make sure you understand how it works before using it)

Comment: Maybe use a class instead of an ID and reference `$(this)` instead of `$(<selector>)` inside of the callback?

Comment: @DBS I just need to copy the text, if you leave only one ```<p>``` the code works perfectly

Comment: @CherryDT can you show an example? I don't know how to handle JS very well yet

Comment: @Ruan see [wahwahwah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228376/1871033), in particular the `$('.copy')` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#copythis').on("click", function(){
    console.log($(this).text() + ": you clicked on '#copythis' ");
});

$('.copy').on("click", function(){
    console.log($(this).text() + ": you clicked on a element with the class 'copy'");
});

$('p').on("click", function(){
    console.log($(this).text() + ": you clicked on a <p> element'");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Something here</h3>
<p id="copythis" class="copy">Copy this code</p>

<h3>Something here</h3>
<p id="copythisone" class="copy">Copy this other text</p>

<h3>Something here</h3>
<p id="copythisone" class="copy">Copy this other text</p>
```

With JQuery, you can use `.text()` to get the contents of a `p` element. You could also change your selector to *just* grab the contents of all 'p' elements. The ID selector `.(#copythis)` will grab the element related to *only* that ID. The class selector `(.copy)` will attach to all elements with the class "copy."

This will help you isolate what's being clicked on. What you want to do with it - copy the contents to clipboard - might change the logic a bit depending on if you have control over the HTML source, and how your deciding what gets copied and doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are planning to do do, but basically this line

```
var text = $("#copythis").get(0);
```

is where the p-node will be selected from your dom an afterwards the content of this p-tag will be copied.

change it to

```
var text = $("#copythisone").get(0);
```

to copy the content of the 2nd p -tag

You could change the id of your third p-tag to sth. like copythisonetoo

```
 var text = $("#copythisonetoo").get(0);
```

to get the content of the 3rd p tag.

But per definition an id should be unique in your document. Refer to this link:
[https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp#:~:text=The%20id%20attribute%20specifies%20a,element%20with%20the%20specific%20id.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp#:%7E:text=The%20id%20attribute%20specifies%20a,element%20with%20the%20specific%20id.)

You could create a method with a parameter for the text to copy or an id.

With some additional info and your certain usecase we could probably help you most.

Comment: Afaik the thing with `get(1)` won't work anyway because jQuery optimizes `#x` selectors to use `document.getElementById('x')`.

Comment: It didn't work, it just doesn't do anything.